# How to safely count sessions: is Session_Start/End in Global.Asax secure/safe enough?

Tags: c#, session

I want to know the amount concurrent sessions at a given time. But with spiders and load-balancers and perhaps influences that do not know about, how safe is it to do this in global asax:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  counter++;
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  counter--;
}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

At very least, this solution has a threading problem (beside other problems that might affect you as you mentioned and I won't cover):

The increment and decrement task should be done in an atomic way using [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(loband).aspx) and [`Interlocked.Decrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y(loband).aspx) methods rather than `++` or `--`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keeping the session stored in a database server or a state server, the Session_End event won't be fired. Else, I think there should be no issues.

Also while incrementing/decrementing a counter, you'll have to obtain a lock on an object like this -

```
lock(<some shared object>)
{
    counter++;
}
```

You can also try taking a look at [this](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/count_your_visitors.aspx).

Comment: Locking on the `global.asax` application object? It's an absolute no-no in an ASP.NET app!